# ios 13 Firebase cloud messages sometimes not received

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am struggling with a very odd problem. Sometimes, for hours no cloud messages are received on my device (both from the Firebase console, and from http request). Then suddenly, it all works fine, (not that I receieve the old messages), but all new ones come it. I change nothing in the code, and its even without reinstall. This applies to topic messages and messages to specific token ids. Why would this be happening?

The times it doesn't work, uninstalling and reinstalling does help. And the result from the message being sent doesn't show any error, and it shows success. But its not getting received at all? This is interesting.

I have been stuck on this for days, and I cannot have it that sometimes the messages are not sent? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my AppDelage code:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

     FirebaseApp.configure()
   
    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]
    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    // [START register_for_notifications]
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
      UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // [END register_for_notifications]
    
   

    
    return true
  }

  // [START receive_message]
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
  }
  // [END receive_message]
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("2124: Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

  // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
  // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
  // the FCM registration token.
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("2124: APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

    // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
    // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
  }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("2124: Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print("2124: \(userInfo)")

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("2124: Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
  }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
  // [START refresh_token]
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("2124: Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    
    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
  }
  // [END refresh_token]
}
```

I'm sending like this from postman (as well as from Firebase console):

```
{
    "to": "/topics/all_dealsAlbaniaios"
     "priority": "high"
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Hi there",
      "title" : "Wow!",
      "sound": "default"
    },
    
    "data": {
        "title": "Hi there",
        "body": "Wow",
   }
}
```